# Можно ли получить id вставленных элементов в mysql одной командой insert?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Использую `mysqli` в `php`.

При вставке одной записи командой `insert`, можно получить `id` вставленной записи. Если же командой `insert` вставлять несколько записей, то получаю все равно один `id` первой вставленной записи.

Можно ли получить `id` сразу всех вставленных записей командой `insert` в `mysql`?

Comment: смысл то в этом какой? какая задача стоит?

Answer (score 1):

Ниразу такого не делал, но если бы встала задача, то попробовал бы через цикл вывести mysqli_insert_id начиная с последнего в том количестве id которое было добавлено. Тоесть если добавилось 3 id то сделать цикл, который выводит id с конца 3 штуки.

Особо не пинайте. Для комментов не хватет 2 балла)

Comment: держи пару балов, но попробуй пример запроса в ответе привести

Answer (score 0):

Вставка нескольких записей (выполняется из PHP-кода):

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... ;
```

Получение id первой из вставленных записей (тоже из PHP-кода, возможно, таким запросом или иным способом):

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Допустим, полученный id мы положили в переменную $id. Количество вставленных записей нам известно, допустим, оно находится в переменной $count Теперь надо получить массив id всеx вставленных записей. Это можно попробовать сделать запросом:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE id >= $id
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT $count;
```

PS. Допускаю, что способ некорректен и может дать неверный результат в многопользовательской среде. Но пока я лично с таким не сталкивался...

Comment: В том то и загвоздка, что при параллельных/конкурирующих запросах вставки, нет гарантии необходимого порядка вставки. Хотелось бы более надежный вариант

Comment: для innodb гарантия более-менее [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872705)

Comment: *при параллельных/конкурирующих запросах вставки, нет гарантии необходимого порядка вставки* Запрос всегда атомарный. Одиночный запрос - фактически транзакция.  А потому надёжность этого варианта если не стопроцентна, то во всяком случае весьма высока. Плюс отсутствие свидетельств (во всяком случае я не видел сообщений о подобном) перемешивания автоинкрементных ID записей, вставленных двумя параллельными запросами.

Answer (score 0):

У mysql нет какого-либо эквивалента `insert .. returning`, а `LAST_INSERT_ID` возвращает только один элемент. Поэтому за один запрос - никак, разве только полагаться на детали внутреннего устройства `auto_increment`.

Имеет смысл не гнаться за одним запросом, а в одной транзакции воспользоваться `prepared statement` и вставить необходимое число строк.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(insert into ...)
foreach ($data as $newrow) {
    $stmt->execute($newrow);
    $dbh->lastInsertId(); // здесь id доступен и корректен
}
$dbh->commit();
```

Что проще по коду нежели собирание одного огромного `insert`, из-за единой транзакции имеет сопоставимый уровень изоляции видимости и число дисковых операций. Остальные ресурсы необходимо измерять, может быть медленнее, может быть равноценно, может даже быть быстрее одного большого запроса - если за счёт prepared statements получится сэкономить достаточно ресурсов на разборе текста запроса.

Comment: я по привычке набросал пример для pdo, а не mysqli. Так что считайте иллюстрирующим псевдокодом. Может быть потом заменю